# How to copy whole vector into queue in reversed order?

Tags: c++, vector, queue, iteration

My vector stores the numbers of the vertices of a certain graph in ascending order. I want to add these numbers to a queue in order to run BFS later in code, but I dont know how do that in nice and fast way. I want the solution to be clear for everyone to read and what I came with is in my opinion obscure. 
Disclaimer - I use static casts because i hate seeing warnings when i work with Qt. Here's what did:

Using casual for loop to iterate in reverse order through the vector starting with `size-1` ending when `i` equals `-1`. Because I'm using `-1` as rule I need to cast everything on `int` which makes code ugly.

```
vector<unsigned> v;
v.pushback(2);
v.pushback(3);
v.pushback(5);

queue<unsigned> q;

for(int i = static_cast<int>(v.size()-1); i>=0; i--)
    q.push(v[static_cast<unsigned>(i)];
```

Can someone tell me how pros do it? Cant find anything like "copy in reverse order" function that can start from `.end()-1` element and copy all elements including `.begin()` one?

Comment: Use [std::rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and `std::rend`

Comment: I knew before that rbegin and rend exists and I couldnt understand why people dont use normal begin() and end() but with swapped places in code, but just right know after reading it again from your link I found our that end() and rbegin() point to a diffrent places in memory, thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` provides the functions [`rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) and [`rend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend) which return reverse iterators that you can use to iterate from the back to the front.  Using those you can use [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) to iterate the vector and then use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as the functor to push each element into the queue.  That would look like

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
std::queue<int> q;
std::for_each(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), [&q](auto el){ q.push(el); });
```